# How to validate primitive parameters passed to a Domain Service?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Say I have some code like the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost) 
    {
        var target = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
        {
           var numberRequired = target / denomination;
           if (numberRequired >= 1)
           {
               yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(denomination, numberRequired);
           }
           target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
        }
    }
```

This is a Domain Service.  How would I validate the cost parameter? Would I have to encapsulate it in a value object and then put the validation in the value object constructor?

For example, I would like to make sure that cost is greater than zero and has two decimal places as I am working with sterling only.

Answer (score 2):

> Would I have to encapsulate it in a value object and then put the validation in the value object constructor?

This is ideal, because wherever else that domain object is used, you know that it is not in an invalid state because its constructor makes that impossible.

As a very rough example, it could look something like this:

```
public class Cost
{
    public Cost(decimal amount)
    {
        var rounded = decimal.Round(amount, 2);
        if(rounded <= 0m)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount), $"{nameof(amount)} must be greater than zero when rounded to two decimal places.");
        Amount = rounded;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; }
}
```

The particulars of how you round may vary. But the point is that it takes place when the value is received from outside your domain and it ensures that every instance of your `Cost` class is valid wherever else it's used, and is immutable.

It may also be worthwhile to use one of the many Nuget packages available for a `Money` type instead of using `decimal`. That way if the price is in a particular currency you can make that explicit. And if you ever deal with more than one currency you won't have the headache of adjusting your code everywhere.

You can also implement `IComparable<Cost>` and `IEquatable<Cost>` so that you can compare instances of `Cost` directly instead of having to compare their `Amount`.

---

This is just a snippet of a Money type that I use. [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plasticfloor.Money), [GitHub](https://github.com/scotthannen/Plasticfloor.Money)

```
public struct Money : IComparable<Money>, IComparable, IXmlSerializable
{
    public Money(decimal amount, Currency currency)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }

    public Currency Currency { get; private set; }

    public static Money Round(Money m)
    {
        return new Money(decimal.Round(m.Amount), m.Currency);
    }
}
```

If you were using something like this then your `Cost` could look like this:

```
public class Cost
{
    public Cost(Money amount)
    {
        if(amount.Currency != Currency.GBP)
            throw new ArgumentException("The currency type must be GPB.");
        var rounded = Money.Round(amount, 2);
        if(rounded.Amount <= 0m)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount), $"{nameof(amount)} must be greater than zero when rounded to two decimal places.");
        Amount = rounded;
    }

    public Money Amount { get; }
}
```

Comment: The number of decimal places is held on the currency object i.e. currency.DecimalPlaces.  Would I inject the currency object into the Cost object (and have a Cost property called: Cost.Currency) or would I just pass the number of decimal places into the constructor i.e. as an int?

Comment: If you have a `Money` or `Currency` type that already encapsulates both the currency and the rounding of decimal places then I would just use that type in place of `decimal`, injecting that and exposing it. In that case the only validation needed would be to ensure that amount > 0. That way if your application has multiple uses for a sterling amount (other than `Cost`) then that validation doesn't have to be repeated. `Cost` might just be an amount of sterling that is always > 0. (I'm saying "might" a lot because of all the details that I don't know.)

Comment: Would you introduce a value object for this? It seems a bit of an overkill.  However, I guess a negative cost value could be passed?

Comment: @w0051977 I think it depends largely on how central the abstraction is toward what you're doing. If a cost is an amount of money which cannot be negative then creating and using a class to represent that means that your validation is always done in one place. If a cost can't be negative but your abstraction allows it to be negative then you have to check all over the place to make sure that your cost isn't negative. The assumption has to built in all over the place that the amount might be invalid.